# Unable to override onBrowserEvent when using GWT TreeViewModel

Tags: gwt, tree, cell

I am trying to use Google web toolkit (v2.5) TreeViewModel to create a tree of cells with one clickable link per cell. I have the tree displaying properly, but I have been unable to figure out how to handle events when clicking on a cell. My class NeoTreeModel implements TreeViewModel, but when I create an AbstractCell in getNodeInfo and try to override onBrowserEvent, I get the compile error "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype". I am not committed to this approach. I would be happy with ANY solution where you can click on a tree of buttons or links and be able to handle the event. I have been trying several hours to accomplish what I thought would be something easy.

```
public class NeoTreeModel implements TreeViewModel {
  private List<NeoTreeItem>  _items    = null;
  private Logger             _logger   = Logger.getLogger("NeoTreeModel ");

  public NeoTreeModel(List<NeoTreeItem> items) { 
   _items = items;
  }

  public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {
    List<NeoTreeItem> list = new ArrayList<NeoTreeItem>();

    if (value == null) {
      for (NeoTreeItem nti: _items) if (nti.getLevel() == 0) list.add(nti);
    } else if (value instanceof NeoTreeItem) {
      list = ((NeoTreeItem)value).getChildren();
    } else {
      _logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Got request for unknown type: " + value);
    }

    ListDataProvider<NeoTreeItem> provider = 
      new ListDataProvider<NeoTreeItem>(list);

    Cell<NeoTreeItem> cell = new AbstractCell<NeoTreeItem>() {

      public void render(Cell.Context context, NeoTreeItem value, 
                 SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        if (value != null) {
          sb.appendHtmlConstant("<a href='javascript:;'>");
          sb.appendEscaped(value.getLongName());
          sb.appendHtmlConstant("</a>");
        }       
      }

      @Override
      public void onBrowserEvent(Cell.Context context, Element parent, 
                     NeoTreeItem value, NativeEvent event, 
                     ValueUpdater<NeoTreeItem> valueUpdater) {

          _logger.log(Level.INFO, "HOWDY2");
        }
      }
    };
    return new DefaultNodeInfo<NeoTreeItem>(provider, cell);
  }
  public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
    boolean result = false;

    if (value instanceof NeoTreeItem) {
      result = ((NeoTreeItem) value).isLeaf();      
    }

    return result;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your code. The prototype of the method onBrowserEvent you are using and the one in AbstractCell are different. The proptotype shuold be -

```
public void onBrowserEvent(Cell.Context context, Element parent, NeoTreeItem value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<NeoTreeItem> valueUpdater )
{
}
```

Difference is ValueUpdater< NeoTreeItem >. In your code it is ValueUpdater< String >

Comment: Sorry, when I said I spent hours on it, I meant I was trying different things, and one of them was to use String instead of NeoTreeItem, and I misses a spot cleaning up the code before I posted it. I fixed that and still have the same problem. I have also tried simply removing the Override statement (no event fires), extending AbstractCell to NeoTreeCell (no difference), using ClickableTextCell instead of AbstractCell (same issues), and ActionCell (events work but was unable to figure out how to label each cell. Thank you so much for your help, though, any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain your actual problem? and the error your are getting?

Comment: My problem is that overriding onBrowserEvent does not appear to work, and therefore I can't detect when somebody clicks on a cell in the CellTree. My understanding is that is the proper way to handle TreeCell events, but I could be wrong. I am about to give up on CellTree and see if I have better luck with Tree and TreeItem.

Comment: Overriding onBrowserEvent method should work.... I our project we overrode it to capture the events. Its working fine for us.

Comment: I eventually needed finer grain control over events and had to revisit this issue. It turns out I was importing com.google.gwt.user.client.Element instead of com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element. Once I made that change it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured it out. Everything I read about overriding onBrowserEvent had to do with cells in a CellTable, not CellTree. Apparently you need to use the selection model to detect when a CellTree cell is selected. Like this:

```
SingleSelectionModel<NeoTreeItem> _selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<NeoTreeItem>();
_selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
      Object object = _selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
      if (object instanceof NeoTreeItem) {
    Window.alert("HOWDY1: " + object.toString());
      }
    }});

   Cell<NeoTreeItem> cell = new AbstractCell<NeoTreeItem>() {

      public void render(Cell.Context context, NeoTreeItem value, 
             SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    if (value != null) {
           // blah
      }
    };

    return new DefaultNodeInfo<NeoTreeItem>(provider, cell,
                        _selectionModel, null);
```